# D3JS - Change colour on setinterval refresh (aka ragging)

Tags: javascript, css, json, d3.js

hoping someone can help here.

I have a few charts on a 500ms refresh using setinterval. On refresh, it loads data from JSON files created by a Python script. I want to be able to RAG (Red, Amber, Green) the data in the charts depending on these values.

Example: If the number is less than 10, then make it green. If it's between 10 and 20, amber, and if it's above 20, red.

I'm using Mike's bullet chart for an example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961

In my CSS I've added the colours - s0 and s1 are present in his example:

```
.bullet .measure.s0 { fill: lightsteelblue; }
.bullet .measure.s1 { fill: steelblue; }
.bullet .measure.s2 { fill: rgb(242, 242, 242); }
.bullet .measure.s3 { fill: #DF4A5E; }
.bullet .measure.s4 { fill: rgb(242, 242, 242); }
.bullet .measure.s5 { fill: #FBAB4A; }
.bullet .measure.s6 { fill: rgb(242, 242, 242); }
.bullet .measure.s7 { fill: #24C678; }
```

In the bullet.js I can then call a function depending on the value of the data, and this will select the correct CSS Class (line 5-13 here):

```
            var measure = g.selectAll("rect.measure")
                .data(measurez);

            measure.enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", function (d, i) {
                    if (d > 20) {
                        return "measure s" + (i + 2);
                    } else if (d > 10) {
                        return "measure s" + (i + 4);
                    } else {
                        return "measure s" + (i + 6);
                    }
                })
                .attr("width", w0)
                .attr("height", height / 2)
                .attr("x", reverse ? x0 : 0)
                .attr("y", height / 4)
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("width", w1)
                .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0);

            measure.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("width", w1)
                .attr("height", height / 2)
                .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0)
                .attr("y", height / 4);
```

This works perfectly, and the color changes correctly based on the values in JSON when I refresh the page, however with my interval refresh it doesn't update.

My refresh is as follows:

```
setInterval(function () {
    updateData();
}, 500);

function updateData() {
  d3.json("mailboxes.json", function (error, data) {
    d3.select("body")
      .selectAll("svg")
      .select('g')
      .data(data)
      .call(chart.duration(500));
   });
};
```

This refreshes the data, but obviously doesn't redraw the rectangles.

I've tried adding in a selector for the measures and then change the class but this doesn't work sadly. (I've also tried SelectAll("svg") and then select('rect.measure') and any combination i can think of.

```
function updateData() {
  d3.json("mailboxes.json", function (error, data) {
    d3.select("body")
      .selectAll("svg")
      .select('g')
      .data(data)
      .call(chart.duration(500));

    d3.select("body")
      .selectAll("rect.measure")
      .data(data)
      .attr("class", function (d, i) {
        if (d > 20) {
          return "measure s" + (i + 2);
        } else if (d > 10) {
          return "measure s" + (i + 4);
        } else {
          return "measure s" + (i + 6);
        }
  });
};
```

Here is an example where the page was loaded when the Support JSON had a value below 10, hence green. The value has since increased to above 10 and should now be amber.

[Green bullet before page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZofw.png)

When I refresh the page, it works as expected

[Amber bullet after page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlm8B.png)

I probably just need a redraw function in the refresh like the below, but I've tried a few things and nothing is working

```
redraw()

function redraw(
  measures.blah
)
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or show us the problem with mock data in another way?

Comment: Tried to create a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/oezpuxvy/1/

Comment: I've had to put the data in hard coded at line 23 of HTML, and take out the json load at line 38 and 76. Weirdly it doesn't display anything :(

Comment: I've created one in Plunker but don't have the option to share it publicly, so it'll probably be messed up quickly!

Comment: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/YHESKRjSBp8YgsVL?preview

Comment: to get the fiddle running you need to also comment the closing brases of the d3.json calls, load d3 before the bullet script (copy code to html) and load d3 with https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the location where you update the class.

Do it before the `transition()`, otherwise the class string will be interpolated and you get a black `rect`

```
        measure.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("width", w0)
            .attr("height", height / 2)
            .attr("x", reverse ? x0 : 0)
            .attr("y", height / 4)
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("width", w1)
            .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0);

        measure
            .attr("class", function (d, i) {
                if (d > 20) { return "measure s" + (i + 2); }
                if (d > 10) { return "measure s" + (i + 4); }
                return "measure s" + (i + 6);
            })
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("width", w1)
            .attr("height", height / 2)
            .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0)
            .attr("y", height / 4);
```

Comment: Wow this one is it! Perfect job sir (I've been stalking your work here for a long while, so it's nice to get a personal reply and to think that I wasn't too far off!)

Comment: This is very confusing as to WHY the attribute updates there correctly, but only on load for the first set. In both you are calling transition, duration and other values, but only on the 2nd one does it change correctly. Is this because it's only the 2nd statement that is called when the chart updates? Confused!

Comment: I only ask this because I have a bar chart that will need to do the same and I'd rather understand it if possible

Comment: @Ewan your version only set the class for the created rects, but you need to do it for the `enter` and `update` selections

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be drawing the chart after you have changed the data so the whole d3 update, enter, exit pattern is not happening, and you need to do that. Your are right, you need a redraw function so I'd suggest creating a function with the main d3 code in it to draw the chart. Call it initially and then when the setInterval fires. Something like the following perhaps (not a working example).

```js
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="bullet.js"></script>
<script>

  var margin = { top: 5, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 120 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 50 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var chart = d3.bullet()
    .width(width)
    .height(height);

//hardcoded data because of jsfiddle

var data = [{"title":"Support","subtitle":"Shared, OOH","ranges":[0],"measures":[12,15],"markers":[12,15]},{"title":"Escalations","subtitle":"Team Leaders","ranges":[0],"measures":[0,0],"markers":[0,0]}]

// load the json here
//  d3.json("mailboxes.json", function (error, data) {
//   if (error) throw error;

// Create a function to draw your chart.
function drawChart() {
    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("class", "bullet")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(chart);

    var title = svg.append("g")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + height / 2 + ")");

    title.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .text(function (d) { return d.title; });

    title.append("text")
      .attr("class", "subtitle")
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .text(function (d) { return d.subtitle; });

    });
  }
  
  // Initially draw the chart.
  drawChart();

  setInterval(function () {
    updateData();
  }, 500);

  function updateData() {
  // this is the refresh for the json
  // d3.json("mailboxes.json", function (error, data) {
  //    d3.select("body")
  //      .selectAll("svg")
  //      .select('g')
  //      .data(data)
  //      .call(chart.duration(500));
  
    // Get some new data and assign to your data var.

    // Draw your chart.
    drawChart();

    });

  };


</script>
```

Comment: Will this redraw not allow the transitions to function though? I'll give it a go now, thanks

Comment: Working in that it draws the chart, but on the interval refresh it isn't re-drawing the measures or markers, as these are in the bultet.js file and aren't called in this drawChart() function :( Am playing with it further